# jQuery Datepicker without any predefined "default" date?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to use the datepicker to choose dates for an online hotel booking tool. I need to have a picker without any predefined "default" date, to let the user do it. At the same time, I want to use the minDate functionality to not let my user choose a date in the past. At this moment, I solved this problem with a very unpleasant hack of the datepicker source code - so, I won't be able to update it, and I really don't like such hacks. Is there a reasonnable, "human" way to do this? I have killed hours working on the question and did not find any working solution.

Comment: hwo do you want to make it work if it doesn't display a default date? Besides, there is a native functionality to handle minDate, did you have a look at the doc?

Comment: Which month should be shown when the datepicker is displayed? I guess, it's the current date? And you could use http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate for the earliest possible date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the datepicker is defined and initialized, you can use `.datepicker( "setDate" , null )` to clear out the default date.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

***NOTE*** This is *not* the same as setting the `defaultDate` option...

Comment: `null` appears to choose today, rather than say "no date".

Comment: What about: ONLY when you don't have a value in that input to make it blank?

Comment: I was asking about the input being empty and the datepicker shouldn't insert anything in it. But the problem in my case was autocomplete. I set it `autocomplete="off"` and now it's fine.