# Bootstrap datepicker today's date selected when calendar open first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, datepicker

I am using this [datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) . 
My issue is when I click on textbox on which datepicker is attached, it opens the calendar with today's date selected.

What I want is when a calendar opens first time it should not have any date selected until a user select a date. 
Example:(Today's Date is 08/06/2014)

[image: Initial screen]

[image: Screen as I click on From]

As in the second picture the calendar opens with today's date selected.

Below is my code for assigning datepicker to textbox

```
$("input[id*=txt_DateFrom]").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            if (pnlValue == 'none') {
                return date.valueOf() >= now.valueOf();
            }
        },
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: false,
        todayBtn: true
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577344/jquery-datepicker-without-any-predefined-default-date

Comment: It's not a duplicate because I am using a different datepicker. It's not JQUERY UI datepicker. PLease check the link of DatePicker that I have posted in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use set date function to set null date. try this its simple.

```
$("input[id*=txt_DateFrom]").datepicker("setDate" , null);
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav I was able to solve it. $("input[id*=txt_DateFrom]").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            if (pnlValue == 'none') {
                return date.valueOf() >= now.valueOf();
            }
        },
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: false,
        todayBtn: true
    }).datepicker("setDate",null);

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
$("input[id*=txt_DateFrom]").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            if (pnlValue == 'none') {
                return date.valueOf() >= now.valueOf();
            }
        },
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: false,
        todayBtn: true
    }).datepicker("setDate",null);
```

I Hope it might help someone..

Answer (score 0):

The problem in selecting current date when using `minDate : moment()`.
Solution: try using like below:

```
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
         format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
         minDate: moment().millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0),
         clear : false
    });
```